# SwaggerUi custom CSS injected but no effect in browser

Tags: css, asp.net-web-api2, swagger

I have a simple [ASP.NET WebApi 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) project where I'd like to use Swagger and customise the CSS slightly. The "flattop" theme by [ostranme](http://meostrander.com/swagger-ui-themes/demo/index.html#) is perfect, and while I've followed the documentation to [inject a stylesheet](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/README.md#injectstylesheet) the CSS seems to have no effect.

I have this in my Startup class where "SwaggerCSS" is the logical name from my embedded resource:

```
c.InjectStylesheet(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Startup)), "SwaggerCSS");
```

I can see in the browser the CSS is under ext/SwaggerCSS but Swagger still looks stock.

[image: SwaggerCSS Source]

Edit:

I should note that the embedded resource is configured directly in the .csproj file:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="swagger-flattop.css">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <LogicalName>SwaggerCSS</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's embarrassing, I haven't implemented Swagger UI yet. Problem solved!